# Swap Slots on Windows Azure but don't copy AppSettings

Tags: azure

I noticed that when I want to swap slots on Azure the whole configuration will also be copied. I have a lot of environment-specific settings that i wanted to have configured automatically on a swap. So for example, i want that the ENVIRONMENT_TYPE of the test slot stays on TEST and doesn't change to DEV.

How to change this option?

**UPDATE: Azure Portal has changed a lot in the past 8 years, question is out of date**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the Azure Preview Portal, you can mark individual AppSettings as "Slot Setting" which means that they won't get swapped. This is described at https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/web-sites-staged-publishing/.

You can access the Preview Portal at https://ms.portal.azure.com/. Choose Browse everything and select your Web-App. On the blade for your web-app, there is a box called Deployment Slots. If you select this, it will list the available Deployment slots - choose the one that you wish to modify, and you can then mark the individual App Settings as "Slot Setting".

Comment: Thank you very much! It's very confusing to me having 2 portals with different functionality. However, it worked. Thanks for spending your time for this answer!

Comment: And yes, screenshot is from the new portal, but i was using the old one when possible :)